# How can I access cookies immediately?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I know this question has been asked by many people regarding cookies, but I am new to programming. I have created a `POST` form in Wordpress and let the people download something by entering their email-address and name so that I can generate lead. But when I am entering data I have to submit the form twice. So is there any way I can access the cookie immediately after setting it?

My code:

```
<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])){ ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('a.down').show().css("display", "block");
    });
</script>

<?php } else { include('login.php'); } ?>
```

Is it possible to use session and cookie variables at same time and show the content first using sessions and later using cookies? I am using cookies to show the data for 30 days.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by _"use session and cookie at same time"_?

Comment: I want to show content using isset($_SESSION) once it done then later content will be display according to cookie, is that possible?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Sessions and cookies are used for vastly different reasons, it would be very strange to have the same data in the session and the cookie.

Comment: Actually my main aim is to show the data after form submission using cookie to show the user for 30 days sessions are not important form me. So is there a way i can access cookie after form submission?

Comment: Actually my client asking me to make it one time submissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using normal PHP variables. At the time you set a cookie in your PHP script, you'll have to create another PHP variable containing the same value.

Example:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['username'])){
set_cookie("username",$_POST['username']);
$username=$_POST['username'];
}
?>
```

At the time you need to read out the variable:

```
<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['username']) OR isset($username)){ ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('a.down').show().css("display", "block");
    });
</script>

<?php } else { include('login.php'); } ?>
```

Comment: I have read this solution somewhere on stackoverflow but the problem is when i am using isset (variable) its not generating the cookie and cookie is not available for the other pages

Comment: Your code working perfectly but when i am trying to load other pages it showing form again.

Comment: i have added your code with some modification and that's working fine but i am getting other issue that my mail function or other functions not working. Setcookie function is taking from your code not from login.php. Could you please help me out?

Comment: I would recommend you to ask a new question if it isn't related to this question.

Comment: Hi i have tried creating two question but both marked as duplicate but those duplicate answer not related to my question. what to do now any suggestion?